# passar parametro para outra página html

Tags: php, html

boa noite preciso de ajuda em html....não estou conseguindo passar o parametro de forma correta para outra página html.

página 1 é uma tabela que é a lista de vagas. Ao clicar no botão da vaga, faz a requisição para a página detalhes. A pagina detalhes é outro form, com todos os detalhes daquela vaga selecionada.
O problema é que não consigo fazer a função que chama o detalhe da vaga do id selecionado.

**Código**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 main">
      <h2 class="page-header">
        Vagas Trabalhadas
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a onclick="generatefile();" class="btn btn-success">Exportar Vagas</a>
        </div>
      </h2>

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="example" action="_class/load_vagas.php" name="listavagas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th valign="middle">RP</th>
              <th valign="middle">Area Atuacao</th>
              <th valign="middle">Alocacao</th>
              <th valign="middle">Data Recebimento</th>
              <th valign="middle">Data Recrutamento Inicio</th>
              <th valign="middle">Status</th>
              <th valign="middle">Pendencia</th>
              <th valign="middle">Analista Universia</th>
              <th align="center" valign="middle">Detalhes da Vaga</th> 
              </tr>
          </thead>

           <tbody>
            <?php foreach($return[0] as $k => $v): ?>
            <tr id-vaga="<?= $v->id_vaga; ?>">

              <td valign="middle" class="Rp"><?= $v->rp; ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" class="AreaAtuacao"><?= $v->area_atuacao; ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" class="Alocacao"><?= $v->alocacao; ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" ><?= dataToSite($v->data_recebimento); ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" ><?= dataToSite($v->recrutamento_inicio); ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" ><?= $v->status; ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" ><?= $v->pendencia; ?></td>
              <td valign="middle" ><?= $v->analista_responsavel; ?></td> 


              <td align="center" valign="middle">
              <img src="imgs/plus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Mais informaÃ§Ãµes" style="cursor:pointer" id="btnloaddetalhes" name="btnloaddetalhes" onclick="loaddetalhes('<?= $v->id_vaga; ?>');"></td>
             </tr> 

            <?php endforeach; ?>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

o problema esta no onclick="loaddetalhes('id_vaga; ?>');"....como levar o id_vaga para a próxima página html. Este dado será usado para carregar toda a informação da página detalhes_vaga.

to fazendo assim: mas não consegui recuperar o parametro

```
function loaddetalhes(idVaga) {
    document.getElementById("id_vaga").innerHTML = idVaga;
    sessionStorage.setItem('id_vaga', idVaga);
    window.open('detalhes_vaga.php');
}
```

quando dei o window.open, mandei recuperar o parametro, para usá-lo na carga de dados com o php, mas não consegui voltar com o 'id_vaga'...vlw

Comment: Da função `loaddetalhes` remove essa linha `document.getElementById("id_vaga").innerHTML = idVaga;`. Verifica se funciona

Comment: já removi...ta na mesma...podem ser duas coisas: 1- não funcionou; 2 - não sei onde achar o parametro passado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que isso podia ser mais simples. Você quer apenas retornar dados do servidor, então basta usar o método GET do http na requisição da pagina detalhes passando o id da vaga. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<a href="detalhes_vaga.php?id=<?php echo $v->id_vaga; ?>">
    <img src="imgs/plus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Mais informações"
    style="cursor:pointer" id="btnloaddetalhes" name="btnloaddetalhes">
</a>
```

Na pagina detalhes_vagas.php você pega o id passado (exemplo: `$_GET['id']`) e faz a consulta no banco e retorna a mesma ou outra pagina como resultado. Opcionalmente você pode remover o onclick da tag img, a não ser que você queira eventualmente fazer uma requisição ajax.

Comment: PQP!!!! vlw Juven!!! FINALMENTE consegui evoluir

Answer (score 0):

No html você pode utilizar `sessionStorage` para passar o parametro.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

e para recuperar:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

Html 1

```
function loaddetalhes(id_vaga)
{
    sessionStorage.setItem('id_vaga', id_vaga);
    ...    
}
```

Html 2

```
function loadVaga()
{
    var id_vaga=sessionStorage.getItem('id_vaga');
    ...
}
```

Comment: vlw tiago, mas não entendo tanto assim. Onde incluo os parametros?

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: to fazendo o seguinte:                                                                                                            function loaddetalhes(idVaga) {
 document.getElementById("id_vaga").innerHTML = idVaga;
    sessionStorage.setItem('id_vaga', idVaga);
    window.open('detalhes_vaga.php');
}

Comment: blz é isso ai...

Comment: legal...mas não consegui achar o dado na  segunda página...fiquei na dúvida

Comment: Utilizando esta função `sessionStorage.getItem('id_vaga');` ?

Comment: isso, pq a outra página chama uma terceira (php) que é quem faz a requisição no banco. Acho que coloquei a função no lugar errado, na segunda página. Pois ela chama o php+banco antes de chegar na função que recupera a variável

Comment: esse session storage é mais seguro que um cookie ou session do php?

Comment: VLW PELA FORÇA TIAGO!!!!